# Casting an IEnumerable<T> to wrapper class

Tags: c#, generics, collections, casting

I’ve got a class that is effectively an IEnumerable wrapper:

```
public class MyThings : IEnumerable<Thing>
{

}
```

I create an Enumerable of `Thing` like this:

```
var things = new [] {new Thing (), new Thing()};
```

From this, I want to create an instance of `MyThings` - something along the lines of:

```
var myThings = things as MyThings;
```

This of course doesn't work.

One solution is to add an `Add` method to `MyThings` and an inner `List<Thing>`

```
public class MyThings : IEnumerable<Thing>
{
    private readonly List<Thing> list = new List<Thing>();

    public MyThings this[int index]
    {
        get { return list[index]; }
        set { list.Insert(index, value); }
    }

    public IEnumerator<Thing> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(Thing thing)
    {
        list.Add(thing);
    }
}
```

This way, I can create it via auto-initialization like:

```
var things = new MyThings {new Thing (), new Thing()};
```

but this doesn't seem very elegant.

Is there a way of casting?

**Edit:**
In the spirit of 'why the hell are you doing this'

It's so we can apply a custom `JsonConverter` to the whole type (`MyThings`)

Comment: ugh, downvoters without comments are up there with the worst things on this site.

Comment: I haven't done Json in .NET before, but I would think most Json serialization frameworks would support collections out of the box.  Can you not simply serialize a `Thing[]`, `IEnumerable<Thing>`, or `IList<Thing>` as long as there is a converter for `Thing`?

Comment: Is this because you want to serialize JSON one way in one place, but a different way in another place, while the underlying type is still the same?

Comment: yeah, it's kind of hard to explain (and out of scope for this question) - but basically our **collection** of `Thing` is stored in a specific way in json (third party requirements) - we have classes that have a property of this type that all need to serialize in the same way, and rather than decorate each property with the JsonConverter, we thought about having this wrapper class - which is almost working well

Comment: @Alex Gotcha.  Might be a good idea to bury the wrapper class in an `Internal` namespace to discourage people from using it outside of the limited scope you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array, from:

```
var things = new [] {new Thing (), new Thing()};
```

is an array (`Thing[]`). It will always be an array, and nothing other than an array. It will not be a `MyThings`.

Now, you could add a *conversion operator* that allows explicit or implicit cast between them, but *quite possibly* all you're doing there is adding an unnecessary intermediate array allocation. Frankly, I think your `Add` addition alongside collection initializer syntax is your best bet.

But yes, you can also add:

```
public static implicit operator MyThings(Thing[] things) {
    // your logic here
}
```

and then this works:

```
var arr = new[] { new Thing(), new Thing() };
MyThings things = arr;
```

or if you use `explicit` instead of `implicit`, then:

```
var arr = new[] { new Thing(), new Thing() };
MyThings things = (MyThings)arr;
```

The operator approach might be a good idea if `MyThings` *just* wraps the array, and you're going to store it in a field without duplicating it, i.e. if your implementation is basically:

```
this._things = things;
```

Comment: I do not like the conversion for the simple fact that it's not immediately clear whether the resulting wrapper is _actually_ a wrapper.  Does it wrap the _original_ array, or does it create a copy?  It's not clear unless you delve into the sources for `MyThings`.  I also question the value of `MyThings` being mutable, but that was OP's design decision, not yours.